# Why does this basic linked list work on MacOS but seg fault on Linux

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a linked list lib I use occasionally on MacOS and I just tried using it on Linux and I'm getting all sorts of problems. I've broken it down into a much simpler version to get to the problems. I've been able to find where the problems are with `gdb`, I just don't know why they're happening. It works fine on MacOs even with address sanitizer. I suspect I might be misusing the pointers here somehow.

here's my list structure:

```
struct node {
  int value;
  struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node node_t;

struct list {
  node_t *head;
};
typedef struct list list_t;
```

And the functions:

```
void list_init(list_t *l)
{
  l = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
  assert(l);
  l->head = NULL;
}

static node_t *new_node(int value)
{
  node_t *new = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  assert(new);

  new->value = value;
  new->next = NULL;

  return new;
}

void push(list_t *l, int value)
{
  node_t *node = new_node(value);
  if (l->head == NULL) {
    l->head = node;
  } else {
    node->next = l->head;
    l->head = node;
  }
}

void print_list(list_t *l)
{
  node_t *tmp = l->head;
  while (tmp) {
    printf("%d\n", tmp->value);
    tmp = tmp->next;
  }
}
```

main function:

```
int main()
{
  list_t *l;

  list_init(l);
  push(l, 2);
  push(l, 4);
  push(l, 6);

  print_list(l);

  return 0;
}
```

`gdb` is telling me that the NULL check in the push function (`if (l->head == NULL)`) is causing the set fault. But it's also telling me that `l->head` is indeed NULL. If i remove that, the seg fault just happens in the next place wherever `l->head` is called.

If i instead I don't declare my list as a pointer...like this:

```
int main()
{
  list_t l;

  list_init(&l);
  push(&l, 2);
  push(&l, 4);
  push(&l, 6);

  print_list(&l);

  return 0;
}
```

It fixes the issue. However, it then makes it as far as the `print_list` function. It will print the list then print a couple more junk values and then seg fault.

I appreciate any help.
And I know no memory is freed here. Just trying to keep the code small to fix the problem.

Comment: Your `list_init` can't possibly work.  C is pass-by-value, so nothing that `list_init` does will have any effect on the pointer variable `l` in `main()`, which remains full of uninitialized garbage.  You ought to get a compiler warning for it (enable `-Wall`!!).

Comment: And your second version doesn't help - when `list_init()` assigns to its local variable `l`, it just loses the pointer it was passed, so again nothing that it does has any effect on the `l` in `main`.  (Btw, for purposes of this question it's really confusing that you're calling all these different things `l`.)

Comment: In `push` and `print_list`, you should also check the input parameters (here check if `l` is null or not). Previous asserts in `new_node` and `list_init` wont prevent that theses functions could be called from somewhere with bad inputs.

Comment: There is no point to the `if` in `push` since the else does the right thing for both branches.

Comment: @stark It's the same code `l->head = node;` in both members of the `if` but it doesn't do the _same_ thing. Look closer to it.

Comment: @Zilog80  I think you should look closer at the result of each branch.

Comment: @stark I see, you mean replace it with  `node->next = l->head; l->head=node;`.. But as `new_node` has still set the `next` member to `NULL`,  the `if` seems still appropriate.

Comment: @Zilog80  When l->head is NULL, setting node->next to l->head is correct, just as it is when l->head is not NULL.  Always set node->next to the rest of the list, regardless whether it is NULL.

Comment: @stark Less code, yes. But doing twice the `NULL` assignation with `NULL` `l->head`. It's not wrong (the cost on the test will be probably on par with the re-assignation), but is less code here better regarding readability ?  let's cut things in two then : `l->head?node->next = l->head:0; l->head=node;`.

Comment: @Zilog80  The cost of a branch is much higher due to cache stall.

Comment: @stark And mostly, the `if` implies on more test each time a new node is pushed. So yes, the `node->next = l->head; l->head=node;` is more efficient with the same result at the end. Thus, let's go with it and a comment stating the twice assignations is then assumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example this function

```
void list_init(list_t *l)
{
  l = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
  assert(l);
  l->head = NULL;
}
```

does not make a sense because the function deals with a copy of the value the argument of the type `list_t *`.

So changing the copy in this statement

```
  l = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
```

does not influence on the original pointer used as an argument. So this function in fact invokes undefined behavior. It does not initialize a list.

So after calling the function as in this code snippet

```
list_t *l;

list_init(l);
```

the pointer `l` stays uninitialized and has an indeterminate value. On the other hand, the function produces a memory leak.

And nothing is changed in this code snippet

```
list_t l;

list_init(&l);
```

because within the function `list_init` after this statement

```
l = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
```

the function deals with a dynamically allocated object of the type `list_t` instead of the passed by reference object `l` declared in main.

To fix the problem define the function `list_init` like

```
void list_init(list_t *l)
{
    assert(l);
    l->head = NULL;
}
```

and call it like

```
list_t l;

list_init(&l);
```

The function push can be written simpler

```
int push( list_t *l, int value )
{
    node_t *node = new_node( value, l->head );
    int success = node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        l->head = node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Correspondingly the function `new_node` can be defined like

```
static node_t * new_node( int value, node_t *next )
{
    node_t *node = malloc( sizeof( node_t ) );

    if ( node != NULL )
    {
        node->value = value;
        node->next = next;
    }
  
    return node;
}
```

Comment: This works. And thanks for the other suggestions too.

Answer (score 2):

Your `list_init` can't possibly work.  C is pass-by-value, so nothing that `list_init` does will have any effect on the pointer variable `l` in `main()`, which remains full of uninitialized garbage.  You ought to get a compiler warning for it (enable `-Wall`!!).

You probably want to have `list_init()` return its pointer instead of trying to pass by reference, so:

```
list_t *list_init(void)
{
  list_t *l = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
  assert(l);
  l->head = NULL;
  return l;
}
//...
int main()
{
  list_t *l = list_init();
  // ...
}
```

Your second version is likewise broken because when `list_init()` assigns to its local variable `l`, it just loses the pointer it was passed, so again nothing that it does has any effect on the `l` in `main`.  You do not need to allocate anything in this version since you are already passed a pointer to a valid `list_t` object.  So if you want to write it this way, then you would simply want

```
void list_init(list_t *l)
{
  l->head = NULL;
}
// ...
int main()
{
  list_t l;
  list_init(&l);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: `head` points to an actual first node or NULL for an empty list.  I think print_list is ok (or would be if list_init were fixed).

Comment: @stark: Oh yeah, you're right.  Removed that part.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate showing both options for `list_init`. Would you say one is preferred over the other or are they considered equally viable?